# Why is there a -1 at the end of the range function?

Tags: python-3.7

I understand the whole code and 
I just want to know why there has to be a -1 at the end of the range function.

I've been checking it out with pythontutor but I can't make it out.

```
#Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where they 
#contain the same length 2 substring. So "xxcaazz" and "xxbaaz" yields 3, 
#since the "xx", "aa", and "az" substrings appear in the same place in 
#both strings.

def string_match(a, b):
  shorter = min(len(a), len(b))
  count = 0

  for i in range(shorter -1): #<<<<<<<<< This is -1 I don't understand.
    a_sub = a[i:i+2]
    b_sub = b[i:i+2]
    if a_sub == b_sub:
      count = count + 1

  return count

string_match('xxcaazz', 'xxbaaz')
string_match('abc', 'abc')
string_match('abc', 'axc')
```

I expect to understand why there has to be a -1 at the end of the range function. I will appreciate your help and explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value indices of the for loop are counted since `0` so the final value actually would be the `(size -1)`

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!